# How can I make a template class within a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-classes

I am working on recreating the forward linked list class so I can better understand pointers. I have hit a roadblock, I have a template class called forward_list. Within this class in the private section I have another class which I want to have the same type as the main (external) class, this class is called node.

```cpp
#ifndef FORWARD_LIST_HPP
#define FORWARD_LIST_HPP

template <class T>
class forward_list
{
    private:
        class node
        {
            T data;
            node<T>* next;
        };
        node<T>* head, tail;
    public:
        forward_list();
        ~forward_list();
        void pushBack(T t);
        void print();
};

#endif
```

When I compile the above code with the rest of my code I produce this error:

```
./forward_list.hpp:11:19: error: non-template type ‘node’ used as a template
   11 |             node<T>* next;
      |
```

I also have tried this (I will add a '*' on the line I have added.)

```cpp
#ifndef FORWARD_LIST_HPP
#define FORWARD_LIST_HPP

template <class T>
class forward_list
{
    private:
        template <class T>   // *
        class node
        {
            T data;
            node<T>* next;
        };
        node<T>* head, tail;
    public:
        forward_list();
        ~forward_list();
        void pushBack(T t);
        void print();
};

#endif
```

Here is the error this change has produced:

```
./forward_list.hpp:8:19: error: declaration of template parameter ‘T’ shadows template parameter
    8 |         template <class T>
      |
```

Comment: Use simply `node`. See [class name injection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name).

Comment: You know you can give template parameters names other than `T`, yes?

Comment: @YSC I found that article really dense :/ are you implying that the use of ```template <class T>``` is not needed above the class node? If that is what you are saying, how do I handle the errors? Could it be something else in my code?

Comment: @Taekahn Yes I do but I want the node to have the same type as the overall class called `forward_list` so that I can make the class overall work as a template.

Comment: @Breadleaf It will, if you do it right. Separate (for illustrative purposes ) the two classes. Get them to compile. Change up the template parameters names (to foo and bar, respectively) then combine the classes again and see what you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is pretty close to what you want. The thing to realize is that while `forward_list` is a class template, `forward_list<T>` is a class, and `forward_list<T>::node` is also a class, not a class template. But also `forward_list<int>::node` is a totally separate class from `forward_list<double>::node`, even though they're both just called `node`.

So, the following would work:

```cpp
template <class T>
class forward_list
{
    private:
        class node
        {
            T data;
            node* next; // Just node*, not node<T>*
        };
        node* head, tail; // Just node*, not node<T>*
    public:
        forward_list();
        ~forward_list();
        void pushBack(T t);
        void print();
};
```

This way `forward_list<int>` will have a nested class `forward_list<int>::node` with an `int data;` member variable, and `forward_list<double>` will have a nested class `forward_list<double>::node` with a `double data;` member variable.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the node is `forward_list<T>::node`, or just `node` within the list. There is no `node<T>`.

In the second case, the problem is that you have two templates both named `T` when you probably wanted two different templates.

So give them different names. :-)

```
template <class T>
class forward_list
{
        template <class U> 
        class node
        {
        };
};
```

Comment: I think the better solution is to drop the `<T>` instead of adding a `template <class U>`, since there's no reason for `U` to be different from `T` anyway.

Comment: Possibly (or likely :-). I'm just trying to explain why the compiler doesn't like the code. Not if it is a useful design...